# Flutter Firebase Invalid Argument Exception

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using `firebase_database` [9.0.4](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_database/versions/9.0.4) in a Flutter app, and at random times running on the physical device, we would encounter the following error.

```
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method cancel on channel userProfiles/***-[DEFAULT]-null-DatabaseEventType.value-[]#1)
-[FIRDatabaseReference encodeSuccessEnvelope:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16d1ec80
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FIRDatabaseReference encodeSuccessEnvelope:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16d1ec80'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1ba83b3d 0x1ad0b067 0x1ba88fd1 0x1ba870c3 0x1b9afdc8 0x26665dd 0x22a1663 0x257bead 0x24da5ff 0x24dd3f7 0x1ba40637 0x1ba40339 0x1ba3fd37 0x1ba3ddd5 0x1b9911af 0x1b990fd1 0x1d13bb41 0x20d13a53 0xb11f7 0x1b17e4eb)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

This does not seem to happen when running on the simulator nor on Android devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded to version 8.2.0 and it seems to have solved the issue. It appears to be an issue with v9.